# WCF - Serialize abstact class and keep it abstract

Tags: wcf, serialization

I am new to WCF; I have an abstract class that in my WCF service.

I am referencing that WCF service from another application that invokes it: I have it added as a Service Reference in my Visual Studio project.

I managed to serialize the derived classes using the ServiceKnownType attribute, but I cannot manage to make the base class automatically abstract in the service reference code.

Any ideas?

Comment: The client could be implemented in a totally different technology than .net where abstract does not mean anything. When building a service, it's better to consider that documents are exchanged, not objects.

Comment: It makes sense :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is something that will work in your case, but you can't (with the normal Add Service Reference tool) directly generate abstract classes.

However, all generated classes are partial, so if you know the namespace, all that's required to make it abstract is a new file with;

```
namespace whatever.the.service.reference.namespace.is {
    abstract partial class MyClass { }
}
```

...and the class will be marked abstract.